# Registering AccountController with Unity IoC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, ioc-container

Account Controller does not Register correctly

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with Individual user accounts using Identity. In my account controller I have a UserMappingService that I would like to inject.

There are two AccountController constructors, the one that was originally an empty constructor is the one that is causing issues. I need to inject the UserMappingService here. Before I added the Service to the parameters of the constructor I was able to make the controller register the empty constructor by adding this to the UnityConfig.cs

```
//parameterless constructor in AccountController.cs
public AccountController()
    {

    } 

// From UnityConfig.cs in RegisterTypes method
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

The problem is that once I add the service as a parameter, I get errors.

```
private IUserMappingService userMappingService;

//constructor with interface in the parameter AccountController.cs
public AccountController(IUserMappingService mappingService)
    {
        userMappingService = mappingService;
    }

//From UnityConfig.cs
 public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IUserMappingService, UserMappingService>();
        container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
    }
```

Resulting error upon runtime is: 
Error in  RegisterType(Invoke.Constructor())
ArgumentException: No member matching data has been found.

I am pretty sure the (InjectionConstructor) is only good for for the default parameterless constructor, but I don't know how else to Register the controller in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can spec the dependency type like this:

```
var ctr = new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IUserMappingService));
container.RegisterType<AccountController>(ctr);
```

Or you can flag your constructor with `InjectionConstructorAttribute`:

```
[InjectionConstructor]
public AccountController(IUserMappingService mappingService)
{
     userMappingService = mappingService;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using option1 - passing the InjectionConstructor as a parameter when registering the type.  Thanks!!